# HTML: Can I mark/highlight a drop-down list menu item?

Tags: javascript, html

Say I've got a list. I want to let the user know that one of the indices was the one that was previously set. I would like it so that when the user opens the drop down menu he can see that one of the options is marked so it looks different from the rest.

Is there a facility for this? I won't bother with it if I have to hack up something ugly or re-implement the entire menu functionality to get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about a simple `<select>`-Dropdown?

If so, it's pretty straightforward with CSS:

```
<select>
    <option style="background:yellow">yellow</option>
    <option style="background:red">red</option>
    <option style="background:blue">blue</option>
</select>
```

Of course CSS-Classes will work, too.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a  element that has  tags inside, 
you could try adding a specific class for option you want to highlight.

```
<option class="myoption"...
```

Then apply background color to this option through css.

```
.myoption {background-color: red;}
```

I think this will not work in IE 6 and 7, because you cannot apply styles for selects in these versions of browsers.

If you have < ul > and < li > elements for list, apply the same method decribed above.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, this would be unnecessary as you would simply have the previously selected option [pre-selected](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.6.1) the next time the page loads when [in state](http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/state.html#whatisstate).

However, if you want to show select-list options in a specific colour, then you can essentially give each option individual css styles, shown in an [example here](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/select-single-option/).

Answer (score 0):

Using the selected attribute on the option tag would be another solution.  See

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

Comment: The selected attribute will select the value as default one and will highlight the value but will not change the style of the selected value.